# Inject File from classpath using Spring Environment

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-3

**My problem: how can I inject a `File` in my class using the `Environment` variable?**

I specify in a `properties` the path of a file I need to read:

```
myFile.path=classpath:myFile.json
```

I used to have an XML application context defining a `property-placeholder` for that `properties.file` and then I simply could inject my file using the `@Value`:

```
@Value("${myFile.path}")
private File myFile;
```

Yet, now I'd like to do something like:

```
@Inject
private Environment environment;

private File myFile;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    myFile = environment.getProperty("myFile.path", File.class);
}
```

But an Exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    classpath:myFile.json (No such file or directory)
```

I also tried something like `myFile = environment.getProperty("myFile.path", Resource.class).getFile();` but an other exception is thrown.

**How can I achieve to inject my file knowing that the path defined in the properties can be absolute or classpath relative?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try injecting the `ResourceLoader`, and use it to load the referenced classpath resource:

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

...

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    String resourceReference = environment.getProperty("myFile.path");
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(resourceReference);
    if (resource != null) {
        myFile = resource.getFile();
    }
}
```